# Troubles using unity test suite with C

Tags: c, unit-testing

I'm working on a test suite with unity and I'm very new to it.
When I run the different tests nothing goes wrong until this one in particular.
Is there something wrong in here? I was thinking maybe a signature error in `TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT_ARRAY(expected,array,3);`

When the function is called in the main it doesn't return anything, while the other tests correctly display PASS

```
static void test_qs_array_three_el_int(void){
  int array[3]={2,1,5};
  int expected[3]={1,2,5};
  quick_sort(array,3,'a');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT_ARRAY(expected,array,3);
}
```

This below is the complete test suite.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "unity.h"
#include "es_1.h"


void setUp(void);
void tearDown(void);

//---------------------test per quick_sort --------------------------

static void test_qs_array_null(void){
  char* array_null=NULL;
  char* expected=NULL;
  quick_sort(array_null,0,'a');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING(expected,array_null);
}

static void test_qs_array_one_el(void){
  char* array={"one_element"};
  char* expected={"one_element"};
  quick_sort(array,1,'d');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING(expected,array);
}

static void test_qs_array_two_el(void){
  char* array[2]={"element_1","element_2"};
  char* expected[2]={"element_1","element_2"};
  quick_sort(array,2,'a');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING_ARRAY(expected,array,2);
}

static void test_qs_array_three_el(void){
  char* array[3]={"2","1","5"};
  char* expected[3]={"5","2","1"};
  quick_sort(array,3,'d');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING_ARRAY(expected,array,3);
}

static void test_qs_array_three_el_int(void){
  int array[3]={2,1,5};
  int expected[3]={1,2,5};
  quick_sort(array,3,'a');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT_ARRAY(expected,array,3);
}

//--------------------------test per binary_insertion_sort--------------------

static void test_bis_array_null(void){
  char* array_null=NULL;
  char* expected=NULL;
  binary_insertion_sort(array_null,0,'a');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING(expected,array_null);
}

static void test_bis_array_one_el(void){
  char* array={"one_element"};
  char* expected={"one_element"};
  binary_insertion_sort(array,1,'a');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING(expected,array);
}

static void test_bis_array_two_el(void){
  char* array[2]={"element_one","element_two"};
  char* expected[2]={"element_two","element_one"};
  binary_insertion_sort(array,2,'d');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING_ARRAY(expected,array,2);
}

static void test_bis_array_three_el(void){
  char* array[3]={"2","1","5"};
  char* expected[3]={"5","2","1"};
  binary_insertion_sort(array,3,'d');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING_ARRAY(expected,array,3);
}

static void test_bis_array_three_el_int(void){
  int array[3]={2,1,5};
  int expected[3]={5,2,1};
  binary_insertion_sort(array,3,'d');
  TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT_ARRAY(expected,array,3);
}


int main(void) {

  //test session
  UNITY_BEGIN();

  RUN_TEST(test_qs_array_null);
  RUN_TEST(test_qs_array_one_el);
  RUN_TEST(test_qs_array_two_el);
  RUN_TEST(test_qs_array_three_el);
  RUN_TEST(test_qs_array_three_el_int);

  RUN_TEST(test_bis_array_null);
  RUN_TEST(test_bis_array_one_el);
  RUN_TEST(test_bis_array_two_el);
  RUN_TEST(test_bis_array_three_el);
  RUN_TEST(test_bis_array_three_el_int);


  return UNITY_END();
}
```

When ran, the output is

```
src/es_1_tests.c:90:test_qs_array_null:PASS
src/es_1_tests.c:91:test_qs_array_one_el:PASS
src/es_1_tests.c:92:test_qs_array_two_el:PASS
src/es_1_tests.c:93:test_qs_array_three_el:PASS
```

Comment: To me it seems that you start with an array that you want to sort and the expected result, which is indeed the initial array correctly sorted from min to max. Then you assert that the arrays are the same. The macro is probably a for loop over 3 elements starting at those two addresses, checking == between the elements. So what is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried `TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT_ARRAY(expected,expected,3);`?  If that works it would indicate `quick_sort` is the problem.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Tried now. That's not it unluckily :(

Comment: You can also print out the individual elements of `array` after the quick_sort.  That will tell you pretty quickly whether the sort actually worked correctly or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm pretty sure the quick_sort function is correct now because most tests actually PASS. The problem is that some of them interrupt the output during the execution

Comment: What does that mean, "some of them interrupt the output during the execution?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey just added to the main post

Comment: Why do your test functions start with `static`?  The examples given on the "Throw the Switch" website don't do this.  http://www.throwtheswitch.org/unity

Comment: Examples or no, @RobertHarvey, it should not make any difference in the OP's case whether the test functions are static or external.

Comment: As you wish.  But that's the only difference I see between the OP's code and the examples provided by the authoritative source.  Since, as you say, it shouldn't matter, prudence dictates that one follows the provided examples *first.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey unluckily thats not it too, thanks for the suggestions man.

Comment: What is es_1.h?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's the quick sort library I needed to create for this assignment. It's a uni project

Comment: [Here is an example that works.](https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/UntidyHelplessSoftwareagent#main.c)  On another note, why did `test_bis_array_three_el` pass, given that you specified the expected values in reverse order?